# Suggested edit icon - misleading UI

Tags: support

After reviewing edits for the given day, I still see the prompt in the header that there are items for my attention.

When clicking on this icon I am told I cannot make further edits for **n** hours.

I personally find this misleading, is there a reason this information is visible if I cannot actually do anything?

If I have misunderstood the purpose of the icon I apologize.

[image: SO UI]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes

Comment: `I personally find this misleading, is there a reason this information is visible if I cannot actually do anything?` Because it would be a feature to hide it when you can't review edits.  A feature that needs to be designed, tested, implemented, etc.  That hasn't happened.

Comment: @JamieKeeling You could leave it here in case someone searches MSO instead of MSE for it, but that's up to you.

Comment: @AstroCB I can't flag it as a duplicate as your URL belongs to a different site. What a wonderful and confusing system this is.

Comment: @Servy It's not a feature to hide it - the user is given an option which is unavailable, why show it in the first place - I see this as an oversight in the design and needs to be evaluated.

Comment: @JamieKeeling The fact that the site doesn't do something that you think it should doesn't meant that that thing isn't a feature.  It most certainly is a feature.  It may be a feature worth implementing, but a feature it is.

Comment: @Servy In this instance scenario we're treading a fine line between  defect or feature. You could argue that it is a feature to change the behavior, however I could say it's a defect which is causing this behavior in the first place. Either way, the existing question mentioned by AstroCB has 100 upvotes and 7 favourites so clearly other users have fallen afoul of this.

Comment: [Well, it depends on how you look at it.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/234170/3150271)

Comment: Feature request: Ability to downvote comments. Rationale: Servy